# React hooks: how to get rid of a state dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In the exemple below, I wonder how to get rid of `items` dependency in the `useEffect()` I want to execute only once to set the interval. What's the best practice around that? Thanks!

```
const Component = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = () => {
      fetchNewItemsSince(items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id : 0) // How to get rid of items dependency
        .then((newItems) => {
          setItems((oldItems) => [...oldItems, ...newItems])
        })
    }

    fetchItems()
    setInterval(fetchItems, 60 * 10000)

    return () => clearInterval()
  }, [items]) // <= I want to get rid of that dependency!!
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that your condition is always truthy? This code doesn't makes much sense

Comment: Also you have a closure on `items`, so it doesn't update the condition as you might think

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. It wasn't the point anyway. ;-D

Comment: How would you set an interval that fetches stuff to append to a state array?

Comment: This "fetched stuff" depends on the items in the array, how you want to call it without having the state in the dep?

Comment: Since you are using `setInterval`, you can make `[items]` to `[]`. So after the mount interval will be set and the data will be fetched as per the defined interval.

Comment: I basically need a state array refreshed every minute, maybe I just did it wrong, I don't know

Comment: I can't remove it currently since it is used in `fetchItems()`. If I remove that method and, let's say I use `useCallback()` and add its dependency to the `useEffect()`, it doesn't make any difference: once the callback is refreshed from the change of `items`, the `useEffect()` is called again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in this snippets like cleaning the interval and calling the cleaning function in `useEffect`, I would re-write this logic to:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const itemsRef = useRef(items);

  const fetchItems = useCallback(() => {
    const [first] = itemsRef.current;
    fetchNewItemsSince(first || 0).then((newItems) => {
      setItems((oldItems) => [...oldItems, ...newItems]);
    });
  }, []);

  // Update ref to dispose closure on `items` state
  useEffect(() => {
    itemsRef.current = items;
  }, [items]);

  // Call once on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems]);

  // Make an interval
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(fetchItems, ONE_MINUTE);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [fetchItems]);
};
```

Comment: I tried to use `useRef` but I did it wrong and this way is working, thanks! We are just missing `fetchItems` dependency in the two last `useEffect()` though. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, although they won't change, it guarantees the same function all component's life time in this specific situation. (Because `useCallback` dep empty)

Comment: It works like this, thanks!

Now I have an issue when I give a callback as a prop `onError` to my component so it's called by the `fetchItems` callback when needed. I added `onError` as a dep for this callback and, in consequence, I'm getting in a loop when `onError` is called.
How come when `onError` is called, everything depending on it as a dep is called? Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Just ask a seperate question please

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, using the [`useInterval` hook from the `react-use` library](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useInterval.md):

```
const Component = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const lastItemId = useMemo(
    () => (items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id : 0),
    [items],
  );
  const fetchNewItems = useCallback(async () => {
    const newItems = await fetchNewItemsSince(lastItemId);
    if(newItems.length) {
      setItems((oldItems) => [...oldItems, ...newItems]);
    }
  }, [lastItemId, setItems]);
  useInterval(fetchNewItems, 60 * 10000);
};
```

Comment: I dont think its a good solution... If you check `useInterval` implementation you just swap the callback, its pretty useless, on every render you clear the interval and restart the interval https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useInterval.ts, and there will be a render because you always add a last item

Comment: Fair point on the clearing of the interval. Added a guard against that. There's also https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useTimeoutFn.md which doesn't reset the timeout when the function changes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure it'd work though, since `useInterval()` would be called at every render.

Comment: Thats wrong too... useTimeout is not interval, if your fetch fails, there won't be another call... When we want to **fetch every 1 min**

Comment: @Alpha60 Based on the source, useInterval is not called at every render.

Comment: @DennisVash Yes, as per the docs, you need to manually call useTimeout's `reset()` to restart; you can do that in a try/finally block.